# Drawing pool table ball trajectory w/o containers

Tags: c++, drawing

The statement of the problem follows:

**Description:**

Write a C++ program that reads the dimensions of a pool table, and prints with 0's the trajectory of a ball after hitting the table in the upper left corner with an angle of 45º.

**Input:**

Input consists of several cases, each with the number of rows and the number of columns. Both numbers are, at least, 2.

**Output:**

Print every pool table as shown in the examples.

**Observation:**

The expected solution **doesn't use vectors or alike**. This includes vectors, strings, arrays, etc. Mathematically speaking, the expected solution uses **O(1) memory in the worst case**.

**Example:**

Sample input:

```
7 4
10 16
```

Sample output:

```
######
#0   #
# 0  #
#  0 #
#   0#
#  0 #
# 0  #
#0   #
######

##################
#0     0     0   #
# 0   0 0   0 0  #
#  0 0   0 0   0 #
#   0     0     0#
#  0 0   0 0   0 #
# 0   0 0   0 0  #
#0     0     0   #
# 0   0 0   0 0  #
#  0 0   0 0   0 #
#   0     0     0#
##################
```

The solution to this problem would be fairly easy if you could use for instance a matrix to keep marking the position of the ball after each movement, and following its trajectory until it hits a corner. But they expect you to not use such data structures (it's an introductory programming course, just to practise), so it's a little bit more difficult.

I've thought of a solution which prints the output pool table line per line, keeping track of the ball position, but the main problem I encountered was being able to predict the position of the ball in cases like the 2nd one (10, 16) where when you print the first line you already need to know that the ball will eventually reach it again twice after some collisions with the table.

Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I believe this can be solved without actually calculating a trajectory, using the width and height and some clever arithmetic, i.e. it's more about finding patterns in mathematics than about simulation in computers.

Comment: Just a small hint: split table image into two, leaving only top-left to bottom-right trajectories on the first and top-right to bottom-left on the second. Then you can notice some pattern.

Comment: @deniss Okay, I notice the pattern, now the problem is to calculate what would be the distance between two '0' that belong to different diagonal trajectories but are in the same row. I find this quite hard, I have been trying to generate some examples to try to see the relationship within the input and the distance but I haven't been able to find it yet. Will keep trying. Anyway, nice hint.

Comment: There is a simple mathematical solution to this problem. But also there is a brute-force algorithm (you can adopt @Mike Vine answer for it), which is still asymptotically optimal. If you want to find the exact equation, imagine infinite number of similar tables placed near each other, mirrored, like in this [image](https://solarianprogrammer.com/images/2013/05/17/squirrel_wrapped_3.png), and follow the ball trajectory.

Comment: Still cannot see the mathematical solution... I've realised that the pattern of the output for input `Rows= r Columns = c` is equal to the pattern for input `Rows = r Columns = c'` where `c' = c + (r*k) - 1, k >= 1 integer`, but this is useless so far.  Mike Vine's solution is asymptotically optimal in memory space usage, but I also need it to be asymptotically optimal in time usage (O(n²)), such a brute force solution is too slow.

Comment: You should solve 'distance problem' with brute force, not the main problem.

Comment: Also take a look at this [picture](http://postimg.org/image/o5nofh8p5/). Try to answer when the ball hit top of the table the second time? The third? When it passes (0,0) coordinates for the second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
int positiveMod(int x, int y)
{
    return ((x % y) + y) % y;
}

int main()
{
    int x,y,sx,sy;
    int startX;
    int minStartX = 0;
    cin >> sy >> sx;

    startX = 0;

    // compute the various start points on x with y=0, keep the smallest to identify the repeating stride
    do
    {
        startX = (startX + 2 * (sy - 1)) % (2 * (sx - 1));
        if ((minStartX == 0) || (startX < minStartX) && (startX != 0))
        {
            minStartX = startX;
        }
    }
    while (startX != 0);


    for(y=0; y < sy; y++)
    {
        for(x=0; x < sx; x++)
        {
            if (
                    (minStartX == 0) && (x == y) || //identity line
                    (minStartX != 0) && positiveMod(x - y, minStartX) == 0 || // top-left quadrant
                    (minStartX != 0) && positiveMod( (2 * (sx - 1) - x) - y, minStartX) == 0 || // mirror against y axis
                    (minStartX != 0) && positiveMod( x - (2 * (sy - 1)) - y, minStartX) == 0 // mirror against x axis
                )
            {
                cout << '0';
            }
            else
            {
                cout << ' ';
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

It still needs the border, and needs fixing for cases where y>x. You can just flip the x/y logic in that case. Hints taken from comments.

Comment: Okay, finally understood the whole thing, I was also trying to solve the problem using @deniss hints but the congruence equations I got didn't work for all cases, I've [rewritten](http://pastebin.com/c0DVebrX) your code, now with the border, and handles the case where y > x just by flipping the x/y logic as you said. Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be to pre-allocate the buffer of the strings to display. Either:

- an array of std::strings, string[y + some].
- a two dimensional array, char[y + some][x + some].
- or a simple char array, char[(x + some)*(y + some)].

*+some* is there for the borders, the '\0' terminals, etc...
You probably want it dynamically allocated with new so you can resize your buffer for each table. Or just allocate something larger that covers the largest table.

Then, fill the buffer with spaces, and draw the border in the array. Start the ball at (0,0), iterate while your not done, putting the '0's in the buffer. Once done, print the whole buffer, line by line.

Comment: As I said, and I will edit the question to make it clearer, the expected solution doesn't use vectors or alike. This includes of course strings (which are essentially vectors of char), arrays, deques, lists, queues, stacks... etc. In other words, the solution uses O(1) memory, so this solution wouldn't be valid.

Comment: K, sorry. Remove the C++ tag then. :-p. This is more a discrete mathematic question. Probably done with the common divider of x and y, and some modulo operations.

Comment: I don't see why I would need to remove it, I need to implement the solution in C++, and in the question I specify some conditions this solution must meet. Of course you can use everything you want as long as it meets the requirement of constant memory use. I've also thought of an approach like you say, but haven't been able to reach to any solution. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I'm sure there's an interesting answer of the form    if ( some mathematic function of x,y,sizeX,sizeY) then print '0' else print ' '.   Otherwise, for a programming class, in O(1) memory, I would just call a function bool SimulateBallUntil(int x, int y) that returns true if the ball ever goes to x,y and returns false if the ball goes back to 0,0 (loops forever never reaching x,y). For each x,y position as you draw the array. Silly inefficient in term of computation, though.

Comment: I'll try to find a solution of the first kind, will post the description of the mathematical function if I'm able to find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Silly implementation of Jeffreys suggestion. Computationally silly, probably easier to do this mathematically but it answers the question...

```
bool SimulateBallUntil(int width, int height, int x, int y)
{
    // start off heading down right
    int xInc = 1;
    int yInc = 1;

    // Start off at pos 0,0
    int curX = 0;
    int curY = 0;

    // Run the path...
    for(int iter=0;;++iter)
    {
        // Check if hit point
        if(curX == x && curY == y)
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Check if hit corner (ignoring the first iteration which is the left corner)
        if(iter && ((curY == 0) || (curY == height-1)) && ((curX == 0) || (curX == width-1)))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Bounce off walls
        if(curX + xInc == width || ((curX + xInc)==-1))
        {
            xInc *= -1;
        }
        if(curY + yInc == height || (curY + yInc==-1))
        {
            yInc *= -1;
        }

        // Move it
        curX += xInc;
        curY += yInc;

    }
}
```